# How do you use these sideways platform?

Tags: rogue-legacy

There are a bunch of platforms that you activate by down-attacking in the air.

[image]

These, however, spawn vertical platforms when you down-attack them, rather than horizontal ones that you can stand on. How do you use these platforms?

Comment: Wow, never seen this ones so far. Since they're placed vertical they're thin, but can't you stand on them anyway? Maybe if you have double/trible jump you could jump on them and activate them, then jump up on the ledge?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can trigger these platforms in the same way as the horizontal ones.  You just have to be very precise with your down-attack.  I would strongly recommend using double jumps and air dashes to traverse the room without having to land on too many of these platforms.

Comment: Can you stand on the miniscule ledge created by this?

Comment: Yes you can but it's quite tricky!

Comment: Honestly, unless you're under attack by something, it's not that tough.